# Mongoid: Is it possible to treat a reference as if it was embedded?

Tags: mongoid

```
class Part
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :type
  # data
end

class Type
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :parts
  field :name
  # data
end
```

Let's say I have a design like the above. I need to have it in such a way that Type exists independently of any Part, both because this is the logical structure and because Types can change and I want to be able to do that centrally. But when I find a Part, I'd like to have it's associated Type embedded in the document returned. I want to do this because in almost any case I need to use the data in a Part, I need the data from its associated Type. When I get the JSON on my client side, it only containes `type_id` but no Type data. Is there any automatic what to include the data from Type in Part's JSON while retaining the benefits of references?

Comment: Also, if it matters, I'm using Sinatra and the JSON module to make the server side of my app.

Comment: How exactly are you producing your JSON? A simple `type.as_json(:include => :parts)` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm using to_json. Is there a way make the include happen by default? Perhaps by overriding some method somewhere.

Comment: You could override `as_json` to include the options you want, you might need to override `to_json` as well.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks for your help. For anyone finding this, you only need to override as_json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, mu answered that one can just override the as_json method of the model.

My implementation is as follows:

```
class Part
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :type

  def as_json options = {}
    if (options.has_key? :include and not options[:include].has_key? :type) or
        not options.has_key? :include
      options[:include] = :type
    end
    super.as_json(options)
  end
end
```